# alguém sabe como resolver um erro na hospedagem de site?

Tags: php, mysqli

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]alguém sabe como resolver um erro na locaweb do disso

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

ele não traz a função proposta na hospedagem da locaweb. resolvi dar um var dump no meu no `localhost` e ele me traz os resultados porem na locaweb ele não me traz esses resultado. eu li que poderia ser a versão por que na locaweb o padrão e a versão 5.2 do `php` intao eu alterei a versão para a 5.6 porem nada não aparece os resultados alguém poderia me ajudar?

bom na minha pagina de detalhe tem esse codigo:

```
 $id = $_GET['cod'];

                        $sqql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = $id");
                        $test = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT votos, pontos FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = $id");

                        $aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sqql);
                        $idprod = $aux['id_produto'];

                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($test);
                        $voto = $row['votos'];
                        $ponto = $row['pontos'];
                        $calc = round(($ponto/$voto),1);
```

ate esse trecho esta funcionando pois dei `var_dump($idprod)` e ela me retorno o id do produto certinho porem continuando agora tem a parte que traz o resultado:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = ?";
                        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                while ($aqq = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                   $nome = $aqq['nome'];
                   $desc = $aqq['descricao'];
                   $preco = $aqq['preco'];
                   $img = $aqq['img'];
```

ja aqui nesse trecho eu dei `var_dump($nome)` o certo seria ele me mostrar string aaaa mas ele nao me mostra nada na locaweb, porem executei o mesmo `var_dump` no meu localhost e inclusive no mesmo local la ele me retorno string aaaa

Comment: Qual erro acontece? se o php5.2 é o padrão eu trocaria urgentemente de hospedagem.

Comment: nao mostra o erro simplesmente nao aparece meus produtos nada relacionado dei vardump nela pra ve o que que acontecia e nada nao mostra nada no vardump ja no localhost me mostra os resultados do vardump

Comment: No inicio da página coloca essas duas linhas, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @rray teria algum outro jeito de usar o método que retorna o resultado para testar se realmente e esse o erro? algo que faca igual ao mysql_result

Comment: Tente ver os logs do apache.

Comment: `Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result() in /home/storage/d/8a/28/hospedagemdes1002/public_html/detalhe.php on line 324`

Comment: Você precisa do mysql instalada, http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php precisa pedir para eles habilitarem

Comment: so eu pedi pra eles e pronto?

Comment: Em teoria sim, manda o link do manual pra eles, explica q para funcionar seu código precisa desse recurso habilitado

Comment: Esse problema ainda persiste na locaweb em 2022, o erro ocorre por que eles não tem habilitado no php o mysqlnd, sendo necessário trocar o get_result para bind_result, em contato com o suporte foi informado que tudo que eles podem habilitar, já está habilitado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não se não for possívle instalar/ o [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) na sua hospedagem, troque [get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) por [bind_result()](http://%20mysqli_stmt_bind_result), que muda é o retorno o primeiro método retorna um array o segundo N variáveis uma para cada campo do field list.

Subistitua:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

O código abaixo sera aplicado para essa consulta `SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = ?`, a tabela parece ter 4 campos.

Por:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $nome, $preco, $descricao, $imagem);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    echo $nome .' - '. $preco .' - '. $descricao .' - '. $imagem .'<br>;
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: eu troquei porem agora ele vai mais que nem o nome o preco a descricao e a imagem ele esta me trazedno `NULL`

Comment: tambem da esse erro `Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /home/storage/d/8a/28/hospedagemdes1002/public_html/detalhe.php on line 324` eu fiz assim ` mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $nome, $preco, $descricao, $imagem);while ($aqq = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) { $nome = $aqq['nome']; $desc = $aqq['descricao']; $preco = $aqq['preco']; $img = $aqq['img']; }`

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, para cada campo na tabela vc precisa de uma variável, o erro diz que tem variaveis de menos.

Comment: fiz assim agora @rray e ele saiu o erro de number of bin mas nao apareceu nada dei o `var_dump()` dnv e ele mostra `null` `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $nome, $descricao, $preco, $categoria, $img, $tipo, $size, $new, $vot, $po);
                    while ($aqq = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {$id = $aqq['id_produto'];$nome = $aqq['nome'];$desc = $aqq['descricao'];$preco = $aqq['preco'];$categoria = $aqq['categoria'];$img = $aqq['img'];$tipo = $aqq['type'];$size = $aqq['size'];$new = $aqq['new'];$vot = $aqq['votos'];$po = $aqq['pontos'];var_dump($nome);`

Comment: peguei cada campo da tabela que eu tenho no produto e passei mas ele me trouxe `NULL` no `var_dump($nome)`

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, vc n precisa fazer ... `$aqq['nome']`, so chama `$nome`